# communicate between a server and a client with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node.js Server:-

```
// *********** Server that receives orders ************ //

// to use features of the http protocol. // 
var http = require('http');

// initialize to empty string. //
var req = "";

// create the server that will receive an order Request. //
var server = http.createServer(function(req,res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
  // when data is successfully received, a success message is displayed. //
  res.on('data', function(data){
        req += data; // received data is appended. //
       console.log("We have received your request successfully.");
  });
});

// An error message is displayed - error event. //
   server.on('error', function(e){
   console.log("There is a problem with the request:\n" + e.message);
  });

// server listens at the following port and localhost (IP). //
server.listen(8000, '127.0.0.1');
```

and then I have a node.js Client:-

```
var http = require("http"); 
var querystring = require("querystring");
var postOrder = querystring.stringify({
        'msg': 'Hello World!'
});

var options = {
        hostname: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 8000,
        path:'/order',
        method:'POST',
        headers:{
           'Content-Type' :'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
           'Content-Length' : postOrder.length
        }
};


var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req.write(postOrder);
req.end();
```

I am trying to figure out how I can make the client post its order to the server and get a response back from the server...either a success message or an error message...using command line.

currently I run the server on cmd line $ node server.js

and then a run the client $ node client.js

but i get no responses.

Comment: I assume you left out `var http = require("http");` and `var querystring = require("querystring");` from client.js when posting?

Comment: yes. sorry i will edit my text and add them to the post.

Comment: is the issue because I have specified a path in the client, '/order' but my server has no path mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that have problems from the server:
The Server must be:

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    if (req.method == 'GET') {

    } else if (req.method == 'POST') {
        var body = '';
        req.on('data', function(data) {
            body += data;
        });
        req.on('end', function() {
         console.log("We have received your request successfully.");
        });
    }
    res.end("ok");
})
```

Comment: what abt the '/order' path i have mentioned in the options object in the client code? does the server need a check if path == '/order' ??

Comment: You can use: if(req.url=="/order"){...}

Comment: oh. the res object does not have a write() function

Comment: one last question:-

say if I want the server to res.end(body)... respond to the client with the message the server received.. I can't seem to send the data back to the client...can u help?